# add_editor_style now copying html styles to .editor-styles-wrapper?

Tags: block-editor, add-editor-style

**Edit:** I didn't adequately research this question before posting it, so the behavior I'm describing is much older than I realized. The issue I was observing comes from elsewhere. Leaving the original question here for context.

---

`add_editor_style` copies the styles of the `body {}` selector from the specified stylesheet into the class selector `.editor-styles-wrapper {}`. This isn't well-documented, as far as I can tell, other than in [a comment](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_editor_style/#comment-5332) in the documentation.

Since upgrading to 6.3 (or possibly earlier), I notice that the styles on `html {}` are *also* being copied to `.editor-styles-wrapper {}`.

So if you load a file like `editor-styles.css` that contains the following declarations:

```css
html {
  font-size: 100%;
}

body {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}
```

WordPress will inject these styles into the editor as:

```css
.editor-styles-wrapper {
  font-size: 100%;
}

.editor-styles-wrapper {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}
```

(Previously, the `html {}` styles would have just been dropped.)

Is this intentional? Is it documented anywhere? This has led to some slight breakages in my editor styles.

Comment: Could you please paste your code to enqueue the style sheet? Since 6.3 my calls to `add_editor_style` are no longer prepending `editor-styles-wrapper` which has broken all my block editor css!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a look at the code history in the Gutenberg repository, and it looks like `html` and `body` have been transformed since the very beginning, 5 years ago:

https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blame/15fc0c13eb33a6e4426ff4ad681b6bfb6d0adaec/packages/editor/src/editor-styles/transforms/wrap.js

`:root` was added several months later.

So yes, it appears to be intentional, but not new. If something has changed in your styles in 6.3 it must be something else. I can't see any meaningful change in how this feature has been implemented since it was introduced.

Comment: Thanks Jacob. I was just looking at exactly the same file and coming to the same conclusion! I think I didn't do enough research before asking this question.